# Python Pandas, New column with minimum value of previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column where the value will be the minimum value of all previous rows from existing columns.

For example:
Here is my data frame:

```
    A  nbr
0  AA    4
1  AB    5
2  AC    2
3  AD    5
4  AE    3
5  AF    6
6  AG    1
7  AH    4
```

I am trying to add a new column 'nbr_min' using the column nbr.

So the first row for nbr_min will be 4, since this is he first row and the minimum of 4 is 4.
Second row will be the minimum of 4 and 5, which is 4.
Third row will be the minimum of 4,5,and 2, which is 2.
And so on...
The final result should look like this.
[image]

I am having hard time doing this in python (with pandas). Any help will be appreciated.
I am very close to conclude that this can not be done with python. So solution in any other way is also welcome.

.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide input data as raw text, or even generation code. Its easier for others to study your issue. Plus you did not show any code showing attempts you made to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`series.cummin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.cummin.html):

```
df['nbr_min']=df.nbr.expanding().min()
```

Or:

```
df['nbr_min']=df.nbr.cummin()
print(df)

    A  nbr  nbr_min
0  AA    4        4
1  AB    5        4
2  AC    2        2
3  AD    5        2
4  AE    3        2
5  AF    6        2
6  AG    1        1
7  AH    4        1
```

Comment: @Sanobabu this should be faster i think. Please consider accepting the answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: More than my original question, I am struggling to format comments in stackoverflow.

Comment: This works. I also did it using iterrows.  To create dataframe:   `data = {'A': ['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH'], 'nbr': [4,5,2,5,3,6,1,4]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)   
df  df['min_nbr'] = 9999   

min_nbr = 9999   
for x, y in df.iterrows():   
    min_nbr = min(min_nbr,y['nbr'])   
    df.loc[x,'min_nbr'] = min_nbr`        A nbr min_nbr
0 AA 4 4
1 AB 5 4
2 AC 2 2
3 AD 5 2
4 AE 3 2
5 AF 6 2
6 AG 1 1
7 AH 4 1

Comment: @Sanobabu actually iterrows is not required for this purpose. cummin is way faster